# display submit button if empty

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to display submit button if db field is empty. It works fine when I'm trying to display just a simple text, but is there a way to display submit form button?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<table><tr><td>". (empty($row['name'])? 'Submit button' : $row['name']) . "</td></tr></table>";
     }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want.

Comment: I want to show HTML code if field is empty.

Comment: Instead of `Submit button`?

Comment: yes, instead of "Submit button" I want to show: "<input type='submit' value='Submit button'>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply print the `html`.

```
echo "<table><tr><td>". empty($row['name']) ? '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">'  : $row['name'] . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to write like that

```
echo "<table><tr><td>". empty($row['name'])? '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">'  : $row['name'] . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<table><tr><td>". if(empty($row['name']) echo  '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">' ;else echo $row['name']) . "</td></tr></table>";
         }
```

Comment: Tell me please how did you put an `if` inside an `echo` ?

Comment: sorry i  forgot to see echo at first.